# Numerical Integration Error

Tags: numerical-integration, convolution

I'm new to Mathematica.
I have written a code for performing a convolution integral (as follows) but it seems to be giving out error messages:

My code is:

```
a[x_?NumericQ] := PDF[NormalDistribution[40, 2], x]
b[k_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 0.0026*Sin[1.27*k/x]^2
c[k_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := {a[x]*b[k, x]}
d[k_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[c[k, x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
Plot [d[k], {k, 0, 350}]
```

It gives the following error message multiple times:

Integrand c[0.00715,x] is not numerical at {x} = {124.67}

And the plot dosen't show up..!
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix it ?

Comment: You can remove curly brackets from the definition of `c`to make it numeric instead of a list.

Comment: It takes a while, but it's doable: `Plot[0.0026 NIntegrate[Sin[1.27 k/x]^2 Exp[-(x - 40)^2/8], {x, 0, ∞}]/(2 Sqrt[2 π]), {k, 0, 350}]`

Comment: If you use `Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"` it's about ten times faster.

Comment: Hmm, a related bug: ``Integrate[(0.0026 E^(-(1/8) (-40 + x)^2) Sin[(1.27 k)/x]^2)/(2 Sqrt[2  Pi]), {x, 0, Infinity}]`` returns a constant `0.0013` (independent of `k`) which does not agree with `NIntegrate`. It seems to be the limit as `k` approaches infinity.

Comment: Thank you all...! @Shadowray,   This process works for the Normal Distribution function, but yields an error for the function a[x_] := 0.00003*(x^2) (1 - x/79.2).....this time it's an NIntegrate error..saying that the integral fails to converge. Changing the limit of integration from infinity to 90 helps, but is there a way to do the infinity integral?

Comment: If you use `Integrate` instead of `NIntegrate`, it will check convergence.  Of  course, it might do it slowly.  You can also sometimes check `Limit[x * f[x], x-> Infinity]`: If the limit exists and is nonzero, then the integral diverges; otherwise the test fails.  Or you can look at `Series[f[x], {x, Infinity, 2}]` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only function definition that needs to have its argument restricted to numeric values is that for `d` since that is the only function that uses numeric techniques.

```
Clear[a, b, c, d]

a[x_] = PDF[NormalDistribution[40, 2], x];

b[k_, x_] = 0.0026*Sin[1.27*k/x]^2 // Rationalize;
```

As @Shadowray pointed out in the comments, the output of `c` should be a scalar rather than a list.

```
c[k_, x_] = a[x]*b[k, x]

(*  (13*Sin[(127*k)/(100*x)]^2)/
   (E^((1/8)*(-40 + x)^2)*
      (10000*Sqrt[2*Pi]))  *)
```

Using suggestion by @MichaelE2 to use `Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"`

```
d[k_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[c[k, x], {x, 0, Infinity},
  Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"]

Plot[d[k], {k, 0, 350}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your inputs!  I tried to follow the same procedure for  a different function: a[x_] := 0.00003*(x^2) (1 - x/79.2). The NIntegrate shows error: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly 
oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. "NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 
recursive bisections in x near {x} = {8.16907*10^224}. NIntegrate 
obtained -1.815272304467489*10^55882 and 
1.815272304467489`15.954589770191005*^55882 for the integral and 
error estimates"

Comment: @Eparishalini - for the `a` given in your comment, the integral does not converge on {0, Infinity}.